# Does Contour support filtering by regex?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

How can I filter my data in Contour to keep only rows for which a given column matches a given pattern?

For example, in SQL, one would `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ~ '^ABC[1-7]'`. However using `column ~ '^ABC[1-7]'` in Contour expression board yields a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

In the Filter board, under the Text tab of the dropdown for the filter condition, use the “matches (x) Regular expression” condition.